# swift hide container view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a UITableView in the main view which looks like this:

[image]

This table goes all the way to the bottom of the screen

I have a container view which looks like this:

[image]

The container view shows only when i hit a textfield on the top so I can pick an entry.  In the storyboard the container view is set to Hidden.

Here is how the storyboard looks like:

[image]

The problem I have is that I cant select any row where the container takes up even if its hidden.  I even tried to set the container view height to 0 when after I have made the selection and clicked on the done button just to see if I can select the row after its hidden:

```
self.view.frame.size.height = 0
self.view.hidden = true
```

[image]

The Container view is hidden again but I cant select "District 3 - 1st Watch" on down rows because the Container View is still there even after I set the size and hidden it

**Update: 5/7/2015**

OK Nothing seems to be working.  What I have noticed is that if I check off the hidden in the storyboard for the container view then it works (as you can see from my screenshot).  But if I dont set hidden then it doesnt work.  I would be fine with not setting the hidden in the storyboard but setting the container view hidden to false doesnt do anything.  I call this method when I tap on the textfield

```
func showContainer(tableSource: [DistrictSubscriptionSource])
{
    println("showContainer")
    self.view.hidden = false        
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would check out the User Interface Inspector and make sure everything is where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is container view having multiple layers of views in the hierarchy.

When using container view, you have a view in the parent view and over that view, another view which is a main view in child scene is placed (this view is accessed with self.view from child controller).

So even when you are setting self.view.hidden to be true, you are not actually hiding the main container view that is present in parent view in your case, table view. So table view is not allowing your table rows to be checked.

You can verify your view placement by going to Debug>View Debugging>Capture View Hierarcy

Answer (score 1):

If the container view is in fact covering it, just do this:

```
self.view.userInterfactionEnabled = false
```